# javascript removing the oldest element in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, operating-system, fifo

I am trying to simulate a First In First Out job scheduling of a cpu using javascript, lets say :

```
var frames = 3, pages = [1,2,3,1,1,6,3,2], result = {};
```

I wanted to loop to achieve this result:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6
  | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2
        3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3
```

Obviously the one who was replaced in the array of results was the on that is pushed earlier, which in this example is '1'

I've came up with this solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < frames; j++) {
      if(!contains(pages[i], result)){
        result.push({life : i, pages : pages[i]});
        if (result.length > frames) {
          var temp = result.pop();
          result[getOldest(result)] = temp;
        };
      }
      console.log(result);
    };
  };
```

if you'd notice i have a function named `contains` and `getOldest` which is pretty much describe what it does, `contains` returns true or false and `getOldest` return the index of the object that contains the oldest `age` property.

But it seem that I am doing it all wrong.. receiving this result instead

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... 1
2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | ... 1
2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | ... 1
```

as requested, the two functions :

```
var contains = function(needle, haystack) {
  if(haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0) return true;
  return false;
}

var getOldest = function(arr) {
  var oldest;
  var count = Object.keys(arr).length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i].life < arr[i+1].life) {
      oldest = Object.keys(arr)[i];
    } else {
      oldest = Object.keys(arr)[i+1];
    }
  };
  return oldest;
}
```

Comment: You should put the contains and getoldest functions up, that may be where the problem lies.

Comment: i think there is none in those functions, but okay, i'll edit

Comment: I'm still having trouble figuring out what you want. The output that looks like `1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 |...`, is that supposed to be 3 successive loops or one loop? If it's a FIFO shouldn't it output `123116`?

Comment: if you look closely, you'll figure out that the samples i provided is top top bottom and left to right, if you are to read the code you'll see that the inner loop has a limit of 3 which means you must have guessed that the sequence is [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [6,2,3] and so on

Comment: Reading the code isn't gonna help much -- it's not working. Can you explain why the `[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]` sequence is in there? I can't understand how the input would produce that.